# A hard square root question

Tags: arithmetic

This is my first question on StackExchange. So my question is:

If $$x = \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt5 +2}+\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt5 + 1}} + \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt5 +2}+\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}{2\sqrt{\sqrt5 + 1}} - \sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}$$
What is the value of $x^2$?

If someone can also tell me how to input mathematical functions on the StackExchange it would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit this post and add some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I edited your post, hope I didn't mess up.

Comment: Tex goes between single or double dollar signs.  \sqrt for square root, \frac or \dfrac for fractions.  Anything longer than one character for formatted input goes in curly brackets{}.  For example, \sqrt49 gives $\sqrt49$.

Comment: you can typeset many beautiful mathematical equations using MathJax on here :)

Comment: @hypergeometric And some really ugly ones like the one above. :)  It can be a lot of work sometimes, but sometimes neatness counts for a lot.

Comment: @Mike - the purpose is to reduce it to something much less ugly and more beautiful like the solutions given below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt 5+2}+\sqrt{\sqrt 5-2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt 5+1}}=\alpha,$$
we have
$$\alpha^2=\frac{(\sqrt 5+2)+(\sqrt 5-2)+2\sqrt{(\sqrt 5+2)(\sqrt 5-2)}}{\sqrt 5+1}=\frac{2(\sqrt 5+1)}{\sqrt 5+1}=2\Rightarrow \alpha=\sqrt 2.$$
Hence, we have
$$x=\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{2}-\sqrt{(\sqrt 2-1)^2}=\frac{3}{2}\alpha-(\sqrt 2-1)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+1\Rightarrow x^2=\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been struggling with this problem for a while now.

Comment: @user3933538: You are welcome. sorry, maybe I wrote too much.

Comment: No you didn't. I can see why your name is math love :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the fastest way to do this is type it into a calculator (or some mathematical tool like matlab or R)

I might very likely have made a typo when entering your formula but my results are

- $x\approx3.288246$
- $x^2\approx10.81256$

please check it yourself!

Comment: Yeah, I know how to enter it in a calculator(using Google!) but I wanted to know how to solve it myself. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}\cdot\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}~=~?$, and $\sqrt{\sqrt5+1}\cdot\sqrt{\sqrt5-1}~=~?$ Also, if $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2$

$-2ab=3-2\sqrt2$, then what are the values of *a* and *b* ?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite get what your strategy was. Does $-2ab=3-2\sqrt2$ or $a^2+b^2-2ab=3-2\sqrt2$. Can you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Thanks.